# Reporting API with cron job - Google app engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-reporting-api

I'm trying to connect to the reporting api to get some data of the percentage of usage of the emails of the users of a domain. I want to do it as a cron job every day so I need some method to authentificate as the admin of the domain authomatically without any admins interaction.

Now I'm using administrator password and login like this

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/hosted/services/v1.0/reports/ReportingData'

url_login='https://www.google.com/accounts/Clientlogin'

auth_request = urllib.urlencode({'accountType': 'HOSTED','Email': _ADMIN,'Passwd': _PASSW})

login = doPost(url_login, auth_request)


for line in login.split('\n'):    

    array = line.split('=',2)   

    if array[0]=='SID':   

        token = array[1]

_REQUEST_TEMPLATE = ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'    

        '<rest xmlns="google:accounts:rest:protocol"\n'    

        'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\n'    

        '  <type>%(type)s</type>\n'

    '  <token>%(token)s</token>\n'

        '  <domain>%(domain)s</domain>\n'

        '  <date>%(date)s</date>\n'

        '  <reportType>daily</reportType>\n'

            '  <reportName>%(reportName)s</reportName>\n'

        '</rest>\n')
```

but I don't want to store the admin's password. I have tried to use Oatuh 2.0 but it seems that I always need the admin's interaction.

Is there any way to do it using consumer_key and consumer_secret?? or any other alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the auth cerentials somwhere - no matter if its a ssl cert authorization, cookie authorization or user/pass credentials - they always have to be available to the scpript/program that is going to use them. If you dont want to store them in the script itself, you might want to store them in configuration file, and make the script read them from there, store in variable and use as needed. You can even store them in the database, but then you have to store database credentials, and so on, and so forth.

Comment: And there is no way to do using the consumer key and consumer secret ?? Of course, storing them somewhere